# Building the bridge in Operation Breakout

Tags: call-of-duty-ww2

What are some tactics I can use to help my team (or myself) build the bridge without constant slaughter?

Known methods:

- Throw smoke on the bridge to mask their position.
- Clear the houses on each side of the bridge with an LMG with FMJ/Extended-Mag by shooting through the walls maniacally.

Answer (score 1):

There really is no better way other than to smoke it and build while others clear the houses. It’s best to go to the far sides of the bridge to build as well because you have more cover. When the bridge is half built, make sure to go behind the barrels when you build. There isn’t an easier method, but It’s definitely supposed to be hard.